# Полтергейст — это КТО или ЧТО?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, склонение, множественное-число, одушевленность

Из телепередачи о старинных европейских замках (о привидениях и призраках):
*По ночам эти **полтергейсты вылезают** наружу.*

Предложение мне показалось не совсем корректным — потому и запомнилось (я всегда считала полтергейст *явлением*).

Вот что нашлось в словаре иностранных слов:
[**полтергейст**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-foreign-term-10575.htm)
{тэ}, -а, **мн. нет**, м.
Явления по видимости беспричинного перемещения или исчезновения предметов, происходящие внутри жилых помещений и объясняемые проделками домового.

Нашлась и книга И. В. Винокурова "[Полтергейсты](https://www.koob.ru/vinokurov_i/poltergeysty)" (Энциклопедия загадочного и неведомого).

Так все-таки, по какому принципу будем склонять "полтергейст" (вижу — **кого** или **что**)?
Правильно ли употреблять слово во множественном числе?

Answer (score 4):

Исходный пример ("полтергейсты вылезают наружу") странен, поскольку **полтергейст** ("шумный дух" по признанному в русском буквальному определению) не является привидением (сам он невидим зрительно или ментально - видеть можно только его проделки) и вообще чем-то геометрически сосредоточенным, - поэтому едва ли можно говорить о "коллективных" действиях полтергейст*ов*, путая их с бесами, демонами и призраками. **Множественное число** возможно, но в контексте рассуждений о классификационных *видах* полтергейста (слава Богу, нет попыток утверждать, что этот дух "един"), или *случаях* его проявления в разных местах. Поскольку это *явление*, распознав которое, люди перестают задаваться вопросом "кто это сделал" и определяют для себя "что это было", то напрашивается местоимение "**что**".

Comment: *Множественное число возможно, но в контексте рассуждений о классификационных видах полтергейста* - как бы вы классифицировали пример из моего ответа про *"книжный" и "посудный" перманентный полтергейст(ы)*? Это что, случай или вид? Мне-то кажется, что ***два полтергейста*** тут вполне уместно (как разговорное), хотя с точки зрения счетности полтергейстов  это наверняка не то, о чем толкует автор той паранормальной монографии.

Answer (score 2):

Это какая-то специфическая область человеческих "знаний" (которая, к сожалению, бурно развивается в последнее время и у нас). Поэтому здесь лучше воспользоваться современными словарями. Например:

> **Полтергейст**, а, м. [нем. Poltergeist грохочущий дух, беспокойный домовой] В уфологии. Таинственное мистическое существо, дух,
>   обнаруживающий свое присутствие и отношение к хозяевам дома неожиданным шумом, перемещением предметов и т. п.

(**Толковый словарь русского языка конца XX века. Языковые изменения.** Под ред. Г. Н. Скляревской. Российская академия наук, Институт лингвистических  исследований. Изд-во «Фолио-Пресс». СПб., 1998.)

Кроме того, согласно словарю Кузнецова этим словом может обозначаться не только явление, но и олицетворение соответствующих сверхъестественных сил в персонаже. Также в этом словаре нет характерной пометы "только ед.", следовательно, слово может иметь форму множественного числа.

Answer (score 1):

Полтергейст — это действительно явление. Подразумевается, что одним словом мы описываем совокупность необъяснимых происшествий, обладающих определёнными признаками и сосредоточенными на одной территории, как правило, жилого помещения одной семьи. Как же его употреблять?

Я прикинул для себя примерную аналогию — мор: большое количество смертей по общей, как правило, эпидемической причине.

В жилищах не описывают два-три полтергейста, а лишь два-три случая полтергейста. Как и сложно представить себе обстоятельства, когда бы мы сказали: в n-ом году в N-ске было одновременно два мора. Режет слух, правда?

Однако форма «моры» допустима, хотя, по каким-то необъяснимым причинам, неблагозвучна. Видимо, просто потому, что почти никогда не употребляется. С полтергейстом похожая ситуация. Форма «полтергейсты», на мой взгляд, вполне нормативна. Конечно, Винокуров — не Розенталь, и более того, судя по количеству книг и тем и отсутствию информации, он ещё и вымышленный человек. Однако оснований раскритиковать популяризированный им выбор употребления не вижу. Как иначе-то вообще?

Если копаться в этимологии, то с немецкого полтергейст — шумный дух. Не совсем отвечает парапсихологическому определению, однако, если абстрагируемся и спроецируем на русский, то что мы получаем во множественном? Полтергейсты — шумные духи. Раз можем сказать на иностранном во множественном, какие у нас основания ограничивать возможности русского языка? Никаких.

Так что лично я смело напишу «полтергейсты», если у меня не будет выбора, но, если он будет, я бы предпочёл: «случаи полтергейста» или «проявления полтергейста», так благозвучнее.

**К вопросу «кто» или «что».** Если обратиться к литературе вроде трудов Винокурова, претендующих на некоторую «научность», то здесь будет однозначное «что». А вот в обывательском общении полтергейст крепко ассоциируется с советским барабашкой — условно персонифицированной силой. Откуда и растут ноги у этого «кто». Употреблять так не вижу смысла, кроме как для шутки или в рамках художественной литературы с намерено комической направленностью.

Answer (score 0):

> Предложение мне показалось не совсем корректным — потому и запомнилось
> (я всегда считала полтергейст явлением).

Да, "полтергейст" - явление, но явление тоже может быть действующим субъектом. Любовь, например, тоже явление, и тоже может в некотором смысле вылезать наружу.
То есть единственно, что может вызывать вопросы - это множественное число, так?!

Вопрос, однако, не очевидный. Предположим, речь идет о двух проявлениях полтергейста. Один такой "полтергейст", скажем, переставляет книги на полке, а второй громыхает посудой на кухне. Ну почему бы не сказать, что это "два полтергейста"?! Конструкция, понятно, разговорная, но уж никак не заведомо неправильная.

Впрочем, есть и другое сомнение. В данном контексте "полтергейст", видимо, употреблено семантически неправильно - либо в силу ошибочного понимания автором или умышленно (своего рода эрратив), либо иронически. Точнее сказать нельзя, контекст нужен побольше.

В таком употреблении слово независимо от мотивов может наделяться не только очевидной предметностью и счетностью, но и некоторой даже одушевленностью, аналогично слову "привидение". Но, как сказал, возникает более серьезный вопрос, а что, собственно, понимает автор под этим словом.

> Нашлась и книга И. В. Винокурова "Полтергейсты" (Энциклопедия
> загадочного и неведомого).

Здесь-то другое понимание, множественность **видов**  полтергейста (см. Alex_ander). В нашем примере речь идет, явно, о случаях, масимум - нескольких проявлениях, состоящих из единичных случаев.